# Selenium in Python: How to comment on every Instagram Post?

Tags: python, selenium, browser-automation

I am trying to make an instagram bot to comment on every post in the feed using selenium. So far, it comments on one post, and that's it. It seems that each post has it's own comment section. The html for a single post is this:

[image]

How would I make it comment on every post? Here is the code I have so far for commenting.

```
commentSection = ui.WebDriverWait(self.driver, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "textarea.Ypffh")))
self.driver.execute_script("arguments[0].scrollIntoView(true);", commentSection)
commentSection = ui.WebDriverWait(self.driver,10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "textarea.Ypffh")))
commentSection.send_keys('yo')
self.driver.execute_script("window.scrollBy(0,-200)", "")
self.driver.find_element_by_xpath("//button[@type=\"submit\"]").click()
sleep(2)
```

Answer (score 0):

This is not the best automation practice in selenium.
For multiple reasons, logging into sites like Gmail and Facebook using WebDriver is not recommended. Aside from being against the usage terms for these sites (where you risk having the account shut down), it is slow and unreliable.

The ideal practice is to use the APIs that email providers offer, or in the case of Facebook the developer tools service which exposes an API for creating test accounts, friends, and so forth. Although using an API might seem like a bit of extra hard work, you will be paid back in speed, reliability, and stability. The API is also unlikely to change, whereas webpages and HTML locators change often and require you to update your test framework.

Logging in to third-party sites using WebDriver at any point of your test increases the risk of your test failing because it makes your test longer. A general rule of thumb is that longer tests are more fragile and unreliable.

WebDriver implementations that are W3C conformant also annotate the navigator object with a WebDriver property so that Denial of Service attacks can be mitigated.